# Get page.session value in flet

Tags: python, user-interface, flet

I'm trying to create a shop's GUI.
My MVP's route_change definition looks like this:

```
    def route_change(route):
        page.views.clear()
        page.views.append(
            ft.View(
                "/",
                [
                    ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Flet app"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                    ft.ElevatedButton("Visit Store", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/store")),
                ],
            )
        )
        if page.route == "/store":
            page.views.append(
                ft.View(
                    "/store",
                    [
                        ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Store"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        ft.TextField(
                            label="amount of items",
                            on_change=lambda value: page.client_storage.set("amount_of_items", value),
                        ),
                        ft.Row(
                            [
                                ft.ElevatedButton("Add to cart", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/cart")),
                                ft.ElevatedButton("Go Back", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/")),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ],
                )
            )
        elif page.route == "/cart":
            page.views.append(
                ft.View(
                    "/cart",
                    [
                        ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Cart"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        ft.Row(
                            [
                                ft.Text("Amount of ordered items: "),
                                ft.Text("page.client_storage.get('amount_of_items')"),
                            ],
                        ),
                        ft.Row(
                            [
                                ft.ElevatedButton("Go Back", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/store")),
                                ft.ElevatedButton("Checkout", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/checkout")),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ],
                )
            )
        page.update()
```

I want to get the user input in "/shop" to "/cart" for the beginning. When that worked I want to use the front-end given information for back-end processing.

`page.session.set` and `page.client_storage`don't seem to work.